# Jetpack compose image rotation pivot

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose

I would like to make animated rotation for image arrow like in the video. Right now I can rotate that image, but the rotate pivot is from center of image, how to change it into edge of image?

Is there any way to change rotation pivot? I already tried by using canvas, but still no progress so far.

here my current code

```
              Column() {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(160.dp),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center

                            ) {
                            IconButton(
                                onClick = {
                                    rotation = 270
                                }, modifier = Modifier
                                    .rotate(315f)
                                    .offset(x = 0.dp, y = -60.dp)

                            ) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Home, contentDescription = "",
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                )
                            }

                            IconButton(
                                onClick = {
                                    rotation = 315
                                }, modifier = Modifier
                                    .rotate(0f)
                                    .offset(x = 0.dp, y = -60.dp)

                            ) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite, contentDescription = "",
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                )
                            }

                            IconButton(
                                onClick = {
                                    rotation = 0
                                }, modifier = Modifier
                                    .rotate(45f)
                                    .offset(x = 0.dp, y = -60.dp)
                            ) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Person, contentDescription = "",
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                )
                            }

                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(70.dp)
                                    .background(color = Color.Red, shape = CircleShape)
                                    .align(
                                        Alignment.Center
                                    ),
                            ) {

                                Image(
                                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp).align(Alignment.Center).rotate(angle),
                                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.gender_arrow), contentDescription = "")
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Expected result

[image]

My progress

[image]

Comment: Did you create the `gender_arrow` drawable yourself? I think it might be the easiest solution to change the drawable so that the arrow starts from the center point of the drawable and goes to the edge of it. Then make the drawable background transparent. Then the regular `rotate` modifier will work as expected.

Comment: yah that is good idea, i've tried and it is work, but i still want to know other approach better than that.

Comment: Use `Modifier.graphicsLayer` with `transformOrigin`. [Sample](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#graphics-modifier-origin)